# Do products of distance functions separate points?

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space without isolated points and of diameter $1$. Let $Y=\{y_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$ be a dense subset of $X$.

Define $g_0\equiv 1$, and for $m>0$ let $g_m=d(\cdot,y_1)\dotsm d(\cdot,y_m)$.

I wonder if $\{g_0,g_1,\dotsc\}$ separates points of $X$ in the following strong sense:

> If $x_1,\dotsc,x_n\in X$, $a_1,\dotsc,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $a_1g_m(x_1)+\dotsb+a_ng_m(x_n)=0$, for every $m=0,1,\dotsc$, then $a_1=\dotsb=a_n=0$.

---

**Some partial progress:**

1. Let's show that WLOG $x_1,\dotsc,x_n\not\in Y$.

Assume that $x_1,\dotsc,x_k\in \{y_1,\dotsc,y_l\}$ and $x_{k+1},\dotsc,x_n\not\in Y$. Then $g_l(x_1)=\dotsb=g_l(x_k)=0$, and $g_l(x_{k+1})=\dotsb=g_l(x_n)\ne 0$.

Take $Z=\{z_m=y_{m+l}\}_{m=1}^{\infty}$, which is still dense in $X$, and let  $h_m=d(\cdot,z_1)\dotsm d(\cdot,z_m)$, $h_0\equiv 1$. Then $g_{m+l}=g_l h_m$, for every $m$. For every $m$ we have
\begin{gather*}
0=a_1g_{m+l}(x_1)+\dotsb+a_ng_{m+l}(x_n)=a_1g_l(x_1)h_m(x_1)+\dotsb+a_ng_l(x_n)h_m(x_n) \\
=a_{k+1}g_l(x_{k+1})h_m(x_{k+1})+\dotsb+a_ng_l(x_n)h_m(x_n),
\end{gather*}
and since we "can" prove the statement with $x_{k+1},\dotsc,x_n\not\in Z$, it follows that $a_{k+1}g_l(x_{k+1})=\dotsb=a_ng_l(x_n)=0$, from where $a_{k+1}=\dotsb=a_n=0$. Now assume that $x_k$ is $y_m$ with the biggest $m$. Then $0=a_1g_{m-1}(x_1)+\dotsb+a_ng_{m-1}(x_n)=a_kg_{m-1}(x_k)$, from where $a_k=0$, and so on.

2. Let us prove the statement for $n=2,3$.

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be distinct. First, assume that $ag_m(x)=cg_m(z)$, for every $m=0,1,\dotsc$. Since $Y$ is dense, there is $m$ such that $d(x,y_{m+1})<d(z,y_{m+1})$. But then either $a=0=c$, or $ag_m(x)=cg_m(z)$ and $ag_{m+1}(x)=cg_{m+1}(z)$ are incompatible. Now assume that $ag_m(x)+cg_m(z)=bg_m(y)$, where $a,b,c>0$. Again, using density, there is $m$ such that $d(y,y_{m+1})<d(x,y_{m+1})$ and $d(y,y_{m+1})<d(z,y_{m+1})$, which leads to $ag_{m+1}(x)+cg_{m+1}(z)>bg_{m+1}(y)$.

3. Similar arguments work if we assume that all of $a_k$ but one are of the same sign. But even if two are positive and two are negative I am at a loss.

Comment: So the $n=3$ case says: If $$a PX + b PY + c PZ = a PX\, QX + b PY\, QY + c PZ\, QZ = a PX\, QX\, RX + b PY\, QY\, RY + c PZ\, QZ\, RZ = \cdots =0$$ where the dots continue $P,Q,R$ through a dense subset, then $a=b=c=0$. It looks true but the setup looks awkward.

Comment: @MattF. you are right, the problem is rather strange...

Comment: In the Euclidean plane, $d(y,x_1)^2-d(y,x_2)^2+d(y,x_3)^2-d(y,x_4)^2=0$ whenever the $x$'s are consecutive corners of a square. That may suggest why the $n=4$ case is non-trivial.

Comment: Update: my previous comment holds whenever the $x$'s are consecutive corners of a parallelogram.

Comment: @MattF. you probaby mean a rectangle, right?

Comment: Yes, the expression is invariant for a parallelogram, zero for a rectangle

Comment: @MattF. I agree that this seems relevant, but I tried to build a counterexample out of it and failed